# Post not showing all content in Vue.js app

Tags: node.js, vue.js, axios

I'm building my first Vue app, most of it works fine, but when I click in a post to open the selected post, it doesn't show properly ( Image, title and content don't show ) in the post page, it show the card with the buttons but not the other content, everything shows in home page.

I hope some kind soul can show me some light...

P.S. I'm a beginner so simple terms would be appreciated.

This is my Home page.

```
   <template>
  <v-container>
    <v-alert border="left" close-text="Close Alert" color="green accent-4" dark dismissible v-if="this.$route.params.message">
      {{ this.$route.params.message }}
    </v-alert>
    <v-row no-gutters>
      <v-col sm="4" class="pa-3" v-for="post in posts" :key="post._id">
        <v-card class="pa-1" :to="{ name: 'post', params: { id: post._id } }">
          <v-img height="250" :src="`/${post.image}`"></v-img>
          <v-btn class="ml-4 mt-3" small outlined color="indigo">
          {{ post.category }}
          </v-btn>
          <v-card-title class="headline">
            {{ post.title }}
          </v-card-title>
          <v-card-text class="py-0">
            {{ post.content.substring(0, 100) + '...' }}
          </v-card-text>
        </v-card>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-container>
</template>

<script>
  import API from '../api'

  export default {
    name: 'Home',
    data() {
      return {
        posts: [],
      };
    },
    async created() {
      this.posts = await API.getAllPost();
    }
  };
</script>
```

and this is my post page

```
    <template>
    <v-container>
        <v-row no-gutters>
            <v-col sm="10" class="pa-4 mx-auto">
                <v-card class="pa-2">
                    <v-img :src="`${ post.image }`"></v-img>
                    <v-card-actions class="pb-0">
                        <v-row class="mt-1 mx-1">
                            <v-col sm="2">
                                <v-btn small outlined color="primary">{{ post.category }}</v-btn>
                            </v-col>
                            <v-col sm="10" class="d-flex justify-end">
                                <v-btn color="success" text :to="{ name: 'edit-post', params: { id: post._id } }">Edit</v-btn>
                                <v-btn color="red" text @click="deletePost(post._id)">Delete</v-btn>
                            </v-col>
                        </v-row>
                    </v-card-actions>
                    <v-card-subtitle class="headline">
                        <h3>{{ post.title }}</h3>
                    </v-card-subtitle>
                    <v-card-text class="grey--text">
                        <p>{{ post.content }}</p>
                        <p>{{ post.created }}</p>
                    </v-card-text>
                </v-card>
            </v-col>
        </v-row>
    </v-container>
</template>

<script>
import API from '../api';

export default {
    data() {
        return {
            post: {},
        };
    },
    async created(){
        const response = await API.getPostByID(this.$route.params.id);
        this.post = response;
    },
    methods: {
        async deletePost(id) {
            const response = await API.deletePost(id);
            this.$router.push({ name: 'Home', params: { message: response.message } });
        },
    },
}
</script>
```

Comment: Use the DevTools to inspect what is inside the `post` Object.

Comment: Thank you for replying, DevTools says <img src="undefined"> and the rest of the tags are there but empty

Comment: So apparently the `post` variable is also empty?

Comment: Yes, apparently, but when I use postman to test the back end it works fine, so it simes to be  something wrong in either the home page or the post page, but I can't tell what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Well, you simply start from the end and trace it back to the beginning. If `this.post` is empty - look who is assigning value to this variable, then inspect that value (which is being assigned). If it is also empty - inspect the function that provides that value, then the functions it depends on (in reverse order) until you find the problem. These are basic debugging skills.

Comment: Thank you, I will try to do as you said